# Is this expression statement in a C programming exam question undefined behavior?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

In a C programming exam question, I found this:

```c
int a, b=0, x=4, y=5;
a=((a=x%y?b+1:y--)&&(x-=y))||(y-=6);
```

Is this expression UB?

I would say no, because of the sequence point (SP) between logic operators and between expressions of `?:`. So, to my understanding, the horrible hack would be evaluated correctly as:

```
      x%y                             this gives 4 (exp is true)
    a=    b+1                         this assigns 1 to a and we have a SP (exp is true)
              y--                     this is not evaluated
                     x-=y             this assigns -1 to x and we have a SP (exp is true) 
                              y-=6    this is not evaluated
a=                                    this assigns the result of the || operator to a (1)
```

Finally `a=1`, `x=-1`, nothing else is changed. Any mistake?

Comment: I believe you are correct about everything.

Comment: My knowledge is a little bit rusty, but I remember from the pre-C++11 time that the standard did not define the order in which logical expressions are evaluated. Given this, if you modify a variable in two parts of a logical expression, you have no guarantee which modification will be done first and thus get undefined behavior. I am not aware if newer standards changed this.

Comment: @D-FENS This isn't C++, it's C.

Comment: It doesn't look undefined to me. Unreadable, unpretty, unsane, but not undefined. :-)

Comment: @D-FENS "if you modify a variable in two parts of a logical expression" --> expect in cases like `&&`, `||`, `? :` which have defined sequence points.

Comment: Re “… the programmer who wrote this…”: No programmer wrote this for a program to be deployed. It is constructed as an example for students to work on. It is important for C programmers to know what the evaluation ordering rules are. Indeed, that is the very question **you** are asking, so it is knowledge you are pursuing. That requires constructing examples where the semantics have to be analyzed using the rules of the language. If you think you can construct a better example to work on to exercise these skills and knowledge, then do it.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice it's a C question. I usually don't comment on C. My bad.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I personally know the professor who prepared these tests. The question was raised because some of the statements were obviously UB. I wasn't sure about this one, but I guess that the SP saved the day.

Comment: You have a ternary ANDed with an expression and ORed with another. The results will either be a binary `1` or `0` (`true` or `false`). There is nothing wrong with the construct -- other than real-world readability. The behavior is defined.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I just wanted confirmation on the sequence points. Something similar, but with bitwise operators `a=(x=x%y)&(y=x--);` is UB.

Comment: A perfect example of "just because you can, doesn't mean that you should "

Comment: @CostantinoGrana you are correct. The `&&` and `||` provide sequence points where the conditional on the left is fully evaluated before the one on the right. As you point out, not so with `&` or `|`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this expression statement in a C programming exam question undefined behavior?
>
> Is this expression UB?

No.

> Any mistake?

No.

I wanted to write some text here, but you have already written the explanation... Nothing for me to do. Notes: There is also a sequence point after `?`. Even if `y--` would be evaluated, because `&&` is a sequence point, it still would be fine.

Comment: You're right. I forgot a SP after `?`. But only `x%y` is evaluated before `b+1`. The `a=` part is not. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Och, you are right, my eyes deceived me and I saw `(a=x%y)?b+1:y--`...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a, b=0, x=4, y=5;
    a=((a=x%y?b+1:y--)&&(x-=y))||(y-=6);
    printf("a=%i\nb=%i\nx=%i\ny=%i\n", a,b,x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
a=1
b=0
x=-1
y=5
```

So I think you are right about everything but I do not think it counts as undefined behavior.

Comment: A programme invoking *expected* behaviour is not a proof for the programme not invoking undefined behaviour...

Comment: @Aconcagu I'm not sure what you mean by this. Run gdb and watch the assembly go through the conditions.

Comment: The question is if the given code is valid or invokes undefined behaviour. This is not answered at all by running the code on one specific – yours – machine. A programme *can* yield the expected output even though actually invoking undefined behaviour. If so, the code might break, though, any time on any other system or with any other compiler. I had such a case where productive code (!) modifying a string literal – UB – worked (better: seemed to work) on vxWorks 6.4, but broke when being ported to vxWorks 7.0...

Comment: @Aconcagua true I didn't consider that. Well how would you prove it is undefined? Or prove it not.

Comment: You need to check against the rules of the *standard*. Are there any rules given there violated? For instance reading and writing the same variable without a sequence point in between is UB, using reserved identifiers is UB, ... If you find such violations of the standard you have UB.